# unable to get the full path to root (/var/lib/docker): canonical path points to a file '/usr/bin/docker'

Tags: docker, docker-registry

docker command :

`sudo dcokerd`

It is failing with below error :

```
INFO[2020-03-12T13:48:44.712934798+05:30] Starting up
Unable to get the full path to root (/var/lib/docker): canonical path points to a file '/usr/bin/docker'
```

Comment: `dcokerd` -- kind of looks like a simple typo ...

Comment: @urbanespaceman based on his shell output it seems that the typo was made when he was framing the question and not when he was executing the command.

Comment: applied presentations and corrected spell mistake

Answer (score 0):

Need more detail on this answer. From the likes of it, [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3127#issuecomment-30095645) should help.

```
stop docker
cd /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt
umount ./*
mv /var/lib/docker $dest
ln -s $dest /var/lib/docker
start docker
```